# Google maps infowindow JSON problem

Tags: json, google-maps

I have recently set up a mobile version of my site and am having a little trouble with the Google Maps V3 infowindows on the mobile version.
I am trying to add some data from my JSON file to appear in the infowindows. I am totally new to JSON and javascript as well really.
Here is the content string that I have for the infowindows on my main desktop site which is working perfectly.

```
var contentString = '<div align="left"><p style="color:#000000;"><a href="http://publicaccessgolf.com.au/' + data.course[i].slug + '" >' + data.course[i].name + '</a><br />' + data.course[i].address + '<br />' + data.course[i].contact + '</p></div>';
```

I want to add this to my mobile site but it will not work, the map either doesn’t display at all or there are no markers displayed. 
Here is part of the code for my mobile site

```
function addMarker(map, position){
    var marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position':  position });
    var contentString = 'Need to add info in here...' ;

    var infoWindow = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addInfoWindow', { 'position':marker.get(0).getPosition(), 'content': contentString });
    marker.click(function() {
        infoWindow.get(0).open(map, marker.get(0));
        map.panTo(marker.get(0).getPosition());
    });
}
```

Any ideas why the code from the normal site would not be working??

Answer (score 0):

Could there be problems with the content, e.g. an apostrophe in data.course[i].name?

Have you tried just doing this (to replace your marker.click() function):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
        map.panTo(marker.get(0).getPosition());
});
```

Comment: No I don't think so, because it is working for the main desktop site. I'm thinking it is just a problem with the contentString variable's syntax for the mobile site. If that makes sense?

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that detail.  No experience yet with maps on mobile, so no idea.  I would suggest perhaps ditching the gMap plugin and just doing all the JS yourself.

Comment: No can do, wouldn't have a clue where to start. The gMap plugin is doing a good job, I just can't work out how to get the content into the infowindow

Comment: Thanks Duncan, but that doesn't address my problem of having the wrong syntax within the contentString variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data of a google.maps.data layer added as geoJson just by calling event.feature.getProperty('nameofproperty'). Where 'nameofproperty' could be numer or string (the name of property in your geoJson-file).

Here a simple example I'm using that works fine:

```
//Load mapdata via geoJson
myDataLayer = new google.maps.Data();
myDataLayer.loadGeoJson("myData.geojson");
var featureStyle = {  
  icon: "mm_purple.png"
  };
myDataLayer.setStyle(featureStyle);
myDataLayer.setMap(map);

//listen for click events and show infowindow
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        myDataLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
        infoWindow.setContent('first property: '+ event.feature.getProperty('myfirstproperty') +'<br /> second proporty: '+ event.feature.getProperty('mysecondproperty') + 
        '<br /> last property: '+ event.feature.getProperty('mylastproperty'));
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);
    });
```